# redirect to current page wp-login

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I am not very advanced in php.
I found function that i can use in WP header - then when login from "small green box" in header user stay on page from that he try to login.
Here is my page with WP: http://www.computers-and-control.com/service/manuals/

Now i have other issue, i copied file /wp-login.php to /wp-logincc.php this new file is used for login in my template WP-Download Manager - when click file - that need login before download than is used /wp-logincc.php for function login.

Problem is that after login from wp-logincc.php i am redirected to "Dashboard/Admin Panel" - i would go back to the subpage i come from.
I use different subpages for downloading files with required login and allways need come back to this one i come from.

I try in my wp-logincc.php code:

```
    <?php
    /**
    * WordPress User Page
    *
    * Handles authentication, registering, resetting passwords, forgot password,
    * and other user handling.
    *
    * @package WordPress
    */

    /** Make sure that the WordPress bootstrap has run before continuing. */
    require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    // dankam tu cos ewentualnie zmienic ---- Redirect to https login if forced to    use      SSL
    $dankam_aaa = apply_filters( 'fromwhereyoucame', $fromwhereyoucame );

    function fromwhereyoucame( $link ) {
    $currenturl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    $link = str_replace( '">', '?redirect_to=' . urlencode( $currenturl ) . '">', $link );
    else
    $link = str_replace( '">', '&amp;redirect_to=' . urlencode( $currenturl ) . '">', $link );

    return $link;
    }               

    if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() && $dankam_aaa ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
            wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
             exit();
    } else {
            wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
      exit();
    }
    }
```

But this do nothing in /wp-logincc.php

(But this enclosed function "function fromwhereyoucame" works in "green box")

Please help to modify wp-logincc.php

Answer (score 2):

why you not using plugin for this https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

there is a setting to set after login same page or dashboard redirect..

or
To achieve this redirect after login, add the following code to the functions.php file for your theme:

```
> if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') ||
> (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location']))
> ) {
>     add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
>     function my_login_redirect() {
>         $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
>         wp_safe_redirect($location);
>         exit();
>     } }
```

another solution to make changes by editing in core

**wp-login.php**

Line 424 - 426...

> } else {      $redirect_to = admin_url();     }
>
> Change to...
>
> } else {      $redirect_to = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];  }

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer!  I try add your code to file functions.php in my theme that is in: /var/www/mcccom/wp-content/themes/candc2/functions.php but no result still redirection is to: /wp-admin/   . I will try your plugin else but i war trying multiple other plugins for redirections purpose and they don't work with this link to login that is created when i need use download file with login with plugin WP-download Manager,

Comment: try another 

edit wp-login.php

Line 424 - 426...

} else {
  $redirect_to = admin_url();
 }

Change to...

} else {
  $redirect_to = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];
 }

Comment: Oh! Many thanks! This 
        else { $redirect_to = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]; }
(but line is 747) works!
You are an expert in Wodpress + php :-)
This was very important issue for me.
This IS SOLVED !

Comment: Your answer is a right! 
I am newbie here, probably i can't add score to your reputation?